# Submitting multiple query transactions in CFscript

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I am having trouble finding the correct syntax to execute multiple MySQL statements at once, like with cftransaction. I'm trying to implement this in a CFC in pure cfscript.

```
<cftransaction>
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SOME_TEMP_TBL;
    CREATE TABLE SOME_TEMP_TBL AS
    (
        SELECT * FROM ANOTHER_TBL
    );
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SOME_TEMP_TBL_2;
    CREATE TABLE SOME_TEMP_TBL_2 AS
    (
        SELECT * FROM ANOTHER_TBL_2
    );
</cftransaction>
```

So I have the SQL statements chained together as a string:

```
var SQL = "
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SOME_TEMP_TBL;
    CREATE TABLE SOME_TEMP_TBL AS
    (
        SELECT * FROM ANOTHER_TBL
    );
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SOME_TEMP_TBL_2;
    CREATE TABLE SOME_TEMP_TBL_2 AS
    (
        SELECT * FROM ANOTHER_TBL_2
    );
";
```

And if I understand right I think I need to use a transaction {} block. But do I put raw MySQL code in there? Currently I'm trying to attach it to a Query object but Base.cfc (Railo) is throwing an error saying the datasource isn't defined.

```
transaction
{
    qTrans = new Query();
    qTrans.setSQL(SQL);
    qTrans.execute();
    qTrans.setDatasource(variables.instance.datasource.getDSN());

    if (good) 
    {
        transaction action="commit";
    } else {
        transaction action="rollback";
    }
}
```

Have also tried just SQL.execute() but of course execute() isn't defined for a string & it wouldn't relate to any DB anyway...

Also, is the if(good) portion required? By default does if(good) test for whether or not a MySQL error occurred? And is transaction action="commit" what actually sends the SQL script?

Do I need to split these up into separate Query objects and run them sequentially? And if so what's the point of even having the transaction block in CFscript?

I know I'm way off here but I'm having a hard time navigating the CF documentation around this. If anyone knows of a good source specifically for CFscript references I could really use one, because I struggle with Adobe's version.

Comment: It is the same code you are using? You are executing before setting the datasource. Usually there is try-catch block wrapped around your executable. If anything goes wrong, you set "good" to false and transaction action can be rolled back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
try {
    transaction {
        qTrans = new Query();
        qTrans.setDatasource(variables.instance.datasource.getDSN());
        qTrans.setSQL(SQL);
        qryRes = qTrans.execute();

        TransactionCommit();
    }
} catch(database e) { 
    TransactionRollback(); 
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Silly mistake on my part. Thank you!